# Laravel and Angular - Can't get UI Router to work properly

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, angular-ui-router

So I am using Laravel as a REST API and I want to use Angular for the front-end. However I wanted to use ui-router. However in the ui-view div it always render the index.php again. I think it is because the catch-all route but I can't fix it. Here is my code:
Web routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/{any}', function ($any) {
    return view('index');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Here is my app.routes.js

```
(() => {
angular.module('estate-app')
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
                controller: 'Home',
                controllerAs: 'home'
            });

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    }]);
})();
```

Has someone used ui-router with Laravel before? How did you integrate it? I get the same index.php in my ui-view div. I think it is because it can't find template url it catches it as a route and renders the index again. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to giv `templateUr` from the root of your website. It means, if you have `/public/home/home.html` -> it will transform to `'/home/home.html'`

Comment: + change .htaccess -> if catching an end file -> show it, otherwise go to index.php => https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Comment: @xAqweRx Tried all of this and more... didn't work. I managed to wire it up with ngRoute however it would be awesome if I can use ui.router

Comment: Do you have request to `/home/home.html` in your browser console?

Comment: @xAqweRx Yes I do. When I click on preview I get the same content I have in my index.php not in my home.html